# Angular how to fit child component with <td> into parent component <tr>?

Tags: html, angular

So basically I want to have child components be in control of generating some content and put each one of them as td element, but it's not working in angular because of the extra div angular generates.

How could I make this work?

```
Parent-component.html

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>something1</td>
    <td>something2</td>
    <app-child-component></app-child-component>
  </tr>
<table>
```

```
Child-component.html

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>

<ng-template #content>
  <td>something</td>
  <td>something else</td>
  <td><app-another-component></td>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: There is nothing as `ngContainer` in Angular, it should be `<ng-container>`

Comment: <ng-container> typo edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS to get the child component's container out of the way:

`:host{display: contents; }`